# Cannot open file 'sfml-graphicsd.lib'

Tags: c++, graphics, window, sfml

I have recently picked up the book `Beginning C++ Game Programming`. I am following the book as precise as I can. I am a Java dev with about 2 years experience who is looking to pick up C++. I thought it would be fun learning it while learning game programming.

So I am getting the error `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sfml-graphicsd.lib'`. I have added the include to the file, I have added the additional include and libs in the C++, Linker and Debug project properties. I will include the code, there is nothing yet I just wanted to see the window that is being created but already getting compiler errors.

I have noticed that the actual file name is `sfml-graphics-d.lib` whereas the compiler seems to be trying to open `sfml-graphicsd.lib`. I have checked the version of `SFML` that I downloaded and it is `Visual C++ 14 (2015) - 32-bit` and I am compiling win32.

Code:

```
// Samurai.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);
    Window(vm, "Samurai", Style::Fullscreen);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Samurai, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sfml-graphicsd.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image]

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Thank you all so much,

Owen

Comment: None of your files you are showing us are named `sfml-graphicsd.lib`.  Did you mistype that name in your linker settings?  Also, those errors are linker errors, not compiler errors.

Comment: I have not, I can add screenshots of the properties windows. In `properties > all configs > c++ > general` the additional include dirs are set to C:\SFML\include, in `properties > all configs > linker > general` the additional libs are set to C:\SFML\lib and I set in `properties > debugs > linker > input` the environment vars to sfml-graphicsd.lib;sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-system-d.lib;sfml-networkd.lib;sfml-audio-d.lib;

Comment: ok, I found the error. It was a spelling mistake in the `properties > debugs > linker > input` there was no `-` in the dll filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was a spelling mistake in the `properties > debugs > linker > input` there was no - in the dll filenames